# Canvas background hide the rects that I added

Tags: javascript, html

I am new here, so please be consider.

I've created a new canvas and created a rects in the canvas , when I set a background to the canvas I have a terrible problem that **The background is on the shapes**

Here is the code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var BB = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var offsetX = BB.left;
var offsetY = BB.top;
var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

var background = new Image();
background.src = "url_to_image";

// Make sure the image is loaded first otherwise nothing will draw.
background.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);   
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=450 height=700></canvas>
```

Thanks

**Edit:**
I found in my code a function of fillStyle that change my background,
so I delete it and instead of this I put this:

```js
var w = canvas.width;
 var h = canvas.height
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = "http://www.girija.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Paznja-Sabranost-450x700.png";
 img.onload = function () {
  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat");
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
 };
    //ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";

    rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    // redraw each rect in the rects[] array
    for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
        var r = rects[i];
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        rect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
    }
```

But every drag of the rect (the rects loaded from stack and can be draggable) the background color of the **rect** change

Comment: Draw your shapes only after your image has loaded.

Comment: Set your background in css like `background-image:url('your_link')` or use css property in js like `canvas.style.backgroundImage = "url('your_link')";`

Comment: @Ramesh - the background not shown with the css

Comment: @John I added it to the answer section.Please check

Comment: Wait what do you want to achieve exactly? You want your background to be shown only where the rectangles are drawn?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background using the css property

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var BB = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var offsetX = BB.left;
var offsetY = BB.top;
var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

ctx.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
ctx.fill();
canvas.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://picsum.photos/450/700)';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=450 height=700></canvas>
```

Comment: I have try this and its not working, the background is on the rects

Comment: You mean that you need to draw a rectangle and set its background?

Comment: I need to draw a 10 rectangle and down of them set image to the main canvas.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

background_image();
function background_image()
{
  background_image = new Image();
  background_image.src = 'https://image.ibb.co/kmV8kz/photodune_2359510_smiles_l_22.png';
  background_image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(background_image, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=450 height=700></canvas>
```